# how does linux shell standard output and error output redirect work when combined?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I am trying to understand fine point of standard and error redirection in linux shell scripting (bourne, bash).

Example 1:

```
cat file1  > output.txt
```

or

```
cat file1  1> output.txt
```

This redirects contents of file1 to output.txt. Works as expected.

---

Example 2:

```
kat file1  2> output.txt
```

kat command does not exist so error is redirected to output.txt.  Works as expected.

---

Example 3:

```
cat file1  2>&1 output.txt
```

Because cat is a valid command and file1 exists, here I would expect same behavior as example 1.  Instead I seem to get contents of both files to screen.

---

Example 4:

```
kat file1  2>&1 output.txt
```

since kat does not exist,  I would expect same behavior as example 2. Instead I get error to screen ("-bash: kat: command not found")

as explained in many on-line manuals, example:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: For your third and fourth example, you tell us what you expect, but not what actually *happens*. Please include the *actual* behavior in your question, not only what you expect.

Comment: true. will add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `2>&1` only tells the shell to redirect file descriptor `2` (standard error) to file descriptor `1` (standard output). It doesn't actually do any redirection of standard output.

For that you have to do it explicitly like

```
cat file1 > output.txt 2>&1
```

Note that you have to do the descriptor-redirection *last* (after the standard output redirection) or it will not work.

This is all explained in [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) (see [the section about redirection](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION)).

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file1 2>&1 output.txt
```

The shell will set up the redirection (stderr to stdout). After that you will have "left" as command executed by shell:

```
cat file1 output.txt
```

That's why you see both contents.

For

```
kat file1 2>&1 output.txt
```

it is the same because only

```
kat file1 output.txt
```

is left after shell sets the descriptors for the command to be executed. And this can't be found => error message from shell.